# Your browser is managed?

Tags: google-chrome

I see on [chrome://management/](http://chrome://management/):

> Your browser is managed Your administrator can change your browser
>   setup remotely. Activity on this device may also be managed outside of
>   Chrome. Learn More

But I live alone, as a private person, without any organization or management. How to see that "administrator", decline his services and stop worrying?

Comment: You use Google account. It is managed either by Google or the organization which owned the domain hosted by Google. So your account (and browser) is managed by your account domain admin. PS. It's just my guess, I can't confirm it.

Comment: Do you have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it doesn't bother me at all.